# How to deploy a specific folder as a package

Tags: visual-studio, npm, deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I have an asp.net MVC project and front-end which build via npm command.

and provide app folder after the build.
[image]

This folder does not include to my csproj file.

When i deploy from teamcity, im use 2 steps.

1. publish application
2. FTP deployment for /app folder (each file separately)

But ftp deployment very very slow.
How can I deploy this folder as 'package'?

Perhaps I can dynamically include it to csproj file, 
or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But ftp deployment very very slow. How can I deploy this folder as
>   'package' ?

Indeed, FTP deploy a folder with many files will be slower. Because it only open a single thread, and only uploads a single file at a time. You can consider zip that folder by a MSBuild target:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="..\.build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ZipPackagePath>bin</ZipPackagePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Zip Files="@(Link)" WorkingDirectory="$(ZipPackagePath)" ZipFileName="output\ZipName.zip" ZipLevel="9" />
  </Target>
```

Note: You need add the nuget package "MSBuildTasks" and you can change the ReleasePath to other folder.

But you still need to unzip that zip file after FTP deploy.

> Perhaps I can dynamically include it to csproj file, or something
>   else?

**Alternatively**, you can **dynamically include it to your project file** and it is what we recommendation.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag, place below scripts:

```
  <Target Name="AddAppFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="app\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

After publishing, the app folder is included in the target location:

[image]

Note:

1. With this target, the folder `app` does not appear in the Solution Explorer(dynamically include).
2. If the `app` folder is generated after building complete, you can change the 
   `AfterTargets="Build"` to `BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform"`, like:

`<Target Name="AddAppFiles" BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform">`

Comment: i added target

`<Target Name="AddAppFiles" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="app\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>`

but this doesn't work

Comment: @ArtemPolischuk, That because you are using asp.net MVC project, whcih does not include the target `Publish`. So  if you using `BeforeTargets="Publish"` MSBuild could not call this target(Only clickonce publish have publish target, WPF, Windows Form etc.). You can change it to `AfterTargets="Build"` or `BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform"`.

Comment: This work, when i trying deploy from visual studio. But, when i deploying from teamcity, that doesn't work.

my TC settings:

Targets: Rebuild
`/p:Platform="Any CPU"
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:Configuration=WebClient.Release
/p:PublishProfile="web"
/p:ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled=True
/p:_DestinationType=AzureWebSite
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
/p:username=zz
/p:Password=zz
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True`

Comment: @ArtemPolischuk, You should check the build log to find the reason why the target not executed. At this moment, I have no TC environment to test your settings. If you still not make this work on TC, you can share your TC configuration and build log, I will try to find some useful info.

Comment: i've added target "Rebuild' to csproj and all work correctly

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Ithas been some time but can you tell me where did you put those nodes <Target Name="AfterBuild">? .csproj or some other file?

Comment: @Genato, Yes, the project file, `.csproj`.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Ok, just to be clear this question is about Visual Studio FTP Publish? If yes, I'am trying to publish Web Forms via FTP Publish. I added MSBuildTasks via Nuget and added exact node as you `<Target Name="AfterBuild">...... </Target>` but at the begining of Publish .zip file is created in folder "output\ZipName.zip" as stated in "ZipFileName" property and Publish continue normally. (Files are sent normal not zipped).

Comment: @Genato, Since I do not have enough info about you, I suggest that you can post a new thread with detailed info about your question, there will be more MVP would like help you, and I will also check it when I free.